# Using java to validate outlook email address

Tags: java, email, outlook

Background: 
There are some invalid email adress in our system. I want to find all these invalid addresses. Some of these address are outlook address and some are instant message (IM) address.

Issue:
I have meet an issue when use SMTP to validate email address.
***SMTP works when validate outlook address like ab1234@outlook.com.
However, SMTP failed to validate instant message (IM) address like bob.archer@corpration.com*** which does exist.

Is there a method using java to ***validate instant message (IM) address.***

Hope for your reply,
Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean for an e-mail address to be *valid*?

Comment: It means this e-mail address could not receive mail.
In my company, we use outlook as work mail box. Some email address is removed and couldn't receive mail any more when its owner was left from our company.

Comment: In another word, this address doesn't exist. (Could be removed, or never created).

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons provides a solid validator that can help you:

https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/EmailValidator.java

You can take a look the link above and use the methods of EmailValidator class.

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking the email format (one or more alphanumeric and/or special characters  followed by @ with several more alphanumeric characters separated by at least one "."), the only way to validate anything is to actually attempt to use it, be that for email or for IM.